# python3 -two list of dict - update one list with a matching key,value pair from another

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

I need to update the dictionaries in `list1` with the values from `list2` -- based on a matching `key, value` pair

EDIT : 
Here  I cannot take the keys in the dictionaries as such -- that also needs to be general. 
condition is if a key,value pair exists in both the lists -- list1 needs to be updated with all the key,value pairs in list2 -- if no match - they needs to be untouched. tomorrow I might need to update ghe flexconnect ot fabric values.

```
list1 = [{
                  "key": "wireless.fabric",
                  "value": ""
                  "descr": ""  
                },
                {
                  "key": "wireless.flexConnect",
                  "value": ""
                  "descr": ""
                },
                {
                  "key": "wireless.primaryAuthServer",
                  "value": ""
                  "descr" : ""
                },
                {
                  "key": "wireless.secondaryAuthServer",
                  "value": ""
                  "descr" : ""

                },
                {
                  "key": "wireless.authMode",
                  "value": "central"
                  "descr": ""
                }
                ]
list2 = [{
                  "key": "wireless.primaryAuthServer",
                  "value": "1.1.1.1"
                  "descr": "primary server details"
                },
                {
                  "key": "wireless.secondaryAuthServer",
                  "value": "2.2.2.2"
                  "descr": "secondary server details"
                }]
```

I have a code snippet - but which gives a syntax error - any help ?

```
for d in list1:
   if(d[k] == d1[k] for d1 in list2 for k in d):
          d[k] = [d1[k] for d1 in list2 for k in d]
```

Syntax error at 3rd line!!

Comment: And what have you tried fair person?

Comment: Turn your `list2` into a `key=>value` map and then loop through your `list1` to update matching keys with a value from the aforementioned map.

Comment: get the key, value pair in list2 -- if the same key,value pair is there in list1 -- update it -- Keep all other dictionaries as such.I am not able to make it -- list2 can be any subset of list1-- so key, value pairs also needs to be generalised

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it a simple enough iteration?

```
for data1 in list1:
    for data2 in list2:
        if data1["key"] == data2["key"]:
            data1["value"] = data2["value"]
            break
```

Note: I think you're representing the data poorly. A much better representation would be something like:

```
dict2 = {"wireless.primaryAuthServer": "1.1.1.1", "wireless.secondaryAuthServer": "2.2.2.2"}
```

Comment: I cannot take the "key", "value" directly -- it can be anything -- but same across all dictionaries

Comment: input is auto generated. I need to iterate through this two lists which I cannot change.

Comment: @RanjuSunil Why not create new dictionaries from the generated input?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is :

for item in list2:
        for index, item1 in enumerate(list1):
            for key in item.keys():
                if key in item1.keys():
                    if item1[key]==item[key]:
                        list1[index]=item
print(list1)